# What is the keyboard shortcut for skipping to landmarks with JAWS 17?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, wai-aria, jaws-screen-reader

I am using JAWS 17 and can't seem to find the keyboard shortcut to access ARIA landmarks.

I have implemented a `role="main"` attribute in my markup and have attempted to access the landmark using <kbd>;</kbd>.  Whenever I try to access this landmark, JAWS replies with "There are no mouse-over elements on this page."

Does anyone know the keyboard shortcut for landmarks with JAWS 17?

Answer (score 1):

In JAWS 17, you access the next landmark (which is called a region these days, btw) by pressing the <kbd>r</kbd> key.

In order to go to the next radio button (that was the previous designation of the *r* key), press <kbd>a</kbd>.

Additionally, you can press <kbd>q</kbd> to jump directly to your `main` region.